# A bit of array manipulation

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, compression

I have a 2d array `String compressedColors[][]`, which is filled with numbers between 0 and n(Where n is the number of colors in an image). Now I'm trying to compress my array even more for writing to a file, and one idea I had is replacing consecutive identical elements with some sort of multiplication operator. As in I'd like:

`compressedColors[0][0]=="1"`

`compressedColors[0][1] == "1"` to become

`compressedColors[0][0]=="2*1"`

`compressedColors[0][1] == ""`

This would need to happen for large numbers of consecutive idenitcal elements, and I only want the compression to go across the second dimension of the array. If two rows are filled with 0's, I want 2 seperate `n*0` values at `compressedColors[x][0]`.

I know this is asking a lot, but any ideas how I could accomplish this? I don't even know where to start...
Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need a String for your 0..n values? Why not an int or BigInteger or something?

Comment: This sounds like run-length encoding, but you're doing it the hard way (why strings?)

Comment: I'm writing to a file, and the idea was to print a dictionary to the file (Saying which number from 0..n is which RGB base 36 colors), and then all my numbers

Comment: Is there a better way to write my array[][] to a file then? It is a string array but all elements are integers, I made it string to attempt my multiplication thing

Comment: Instead of your multiplication thing (which requires strings), you can add another position in the array to indicate the number of repetitions of the value that follows. Instead of compressedColors[0][0] = "2*1", you would do compressedColors[0][0] = 2, compressedColors[0][0] = 1.

Comment: `[0][0] = 2, [0][0] = 1` Huh?

Comment: A common way is to use a specific value as "special character" that introduces a run of characters rather than being treated as a literal, downside is that you have to use a run of 1 (rather than a literal) if you want to encode that same value. In many formats that is not a problem because they are not constrained to a symbol set that is 1 too small (often using variable length encoding like Huffman). Using strings is uncommon, but also happens (wastes a lot of space, but is human readable to some degree).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an example which should at least give you an idea how to achieve a solution to your problem. I didn't have a chance to test this out right now so I'm not sure if this will work without modifications.

```
public static String[][] compress(String[][] sArray){
    for(String s[] : sArray){
        int current = 0;
        while(current <= s.length){
            int sequentials = 1;
            while(s[current].equals(s[current+sequentials])){
                s[current+sequentials] = "";
                sequentials++;
                if(current+sequentials>s.length) 
                    break;
            }
            if(sequentials > 1) s[current] = sequentials+"*"+s[current];
            current++;
        }
    }   
    return sArray;
}
```

Comment: Ah I actually just posted a new, more specific question, whoops :P I'll take a look through this though and see if I can work it out, thanks

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question you need to implement both compression and de-compression.

The algorithm for compression (thanks @harold for the term "run-length encoding"), would be something like:

```
  // for an uncompressed image of height h and width w, stored in int colors[][]

  for row = 0 to height
    for column = 0 to width

      // gets the value
      value = colors[row][column]

      // calculates how long the value repeats
      runLength = 0
      nextValue = value
      i = 0
      while(nextValue == value)
        i++
        runLength++
        nextValue = colors[row][column + i]

      // sets the runlength and the value
      compressedColors[row][column] = runLength
      compressedColors[row][column + 1] = value

      // moves to next different value
      column = column + runLength
```

Then, to decompress, you need to interpret every odd column as a run-length and every even column as a value.